# Product attribute not loading

Tags: product

I have an attribute called main_category belonging to a product. When I load the product the attribute does not load with it.

If I do a

```
      var_dump($product)
```

it is not included in the array.

I don't want to load the full product by doing

```
    $product->load();
```

How can I just get this attribute without loading every attribute for each product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed it by making a simple call just to the products attribute without loading the full product. Seems to be a good solution as it uses minimum resources.

```
    $mainCat = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(), 'main_category');
```